# Showing Last Sold Date In a Netsuite ITEM Saved Search

Tags: netsuite, inventory-management, saved-searches

I've created a search that shows current inventory on hand, their purchase price, and a formula that multiplies the two to have current value.

In the results field I want to have a column that shows the last time an item was on a sales order. but i am coming up short. Is there a way to do this?
[Filter Criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/638Rg.png)
[Results Criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hslk.png)

Answer (score 1):

Criteria -
Inactive - FALS
Type - Inventory Item
Transaction Field: Type - Sales Order
Available - Is greater than 0

RESULTS -
Name - (Summary Type Group)
Description - (Summary Type Group)
Available - (Summary Type Count)
Transaction Fields - Date (Summary Type Maximum)

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the saved search from the Item Record or Transaction Record?

If you created it from the Transaction Record then you will want to make sure to use the Date Field and Summary Type (Results tab) as Maximum.

Field = Date
Summary Type = Maximum

If you created the saved search from the Item Record you will need to use the Transaction Fields... table join to bring in the Transaction Date field.

Comment: yes it is a Item Search. However, in the results i can't seem to show the last sale date in the transaction fields. i just need to know when the last time the item was either: sold, shipped or fulfilled. i can use actual ship date but that shows every date that the item was sold on and is an abundance of unnecessary data